# GupShup Flow Bot Builder Goto option not working

Tags: gupshup

Use GoTo option following gupshup documentations to go from state (user select option to return to main menu).
I get the following warning message.
"The selected node has user child states. If you select this state, your bot will wait for
user inputs to continue the flow".

screenshot:

[image]

and it is not working as expected, and we want to show the main menu to user again.

Answer (score 0):

Goto works differently. If you want to execute a certain bot-state, you need to go-to to that state's previous state.

Comment: when I configure it to go to the initial state ,it's not executed.